# What do these vertical lines mean in a cross validation result?

Tags: regression, cross-validation, deep-learning

I'm doing a regression problem using a convolutional neural network. When I was checking my model using 6-fold cross validation. There are always several vertical lines in which samples are dramatically predicted incorrectly. I tried tuning many parameters, the Pearson correlation coefficient will increase or decrease. But no matter what my model is, there are always those vertical lines.

I just have no idea what does these vertical lines mean. What does it imply my model's capability?

---

More details:

## Data

My data are binary encoded sequence data, just like '010001001'. The input sequence are 9-length sequence ,I padded as 13-length.

## Model

Input layer (1x13)

||

Conv layer (512 filters, 1x2)

||

Batch_norm

||

Exponential Linear Units

||

MaxPool (1x2)

||

Conv layer (512 filters, 1x3)

||

Batch_norm

||

Exponential Linear Units

||

Fully connected layer (400 neurons), use `tanh` activation

||

Fully connected layer (1 neuron), output layer

[image: Cross Validation result]

Comment: Can you say more about your data & your model?

Comment: What is the output variable? What do you mean by "sequence", are the numbers temporally related (first it was a 0, then it was a 1, then...)? If the sequences are all of length 9, why would you pad them to 13 (I assume you mean you added extra digits at the end)?

Comment: Good idea to post your data, but take into account that this is a Stats site, not the Keras users forum. If you want to maximize the likelihood of a good answer, you should describe the architecture of your net in words: just posting the Keras instructions won't help someone who's familiar with the ideas behind deep learning, but not specifically with the Keras API. BTW, congratulations on your choice! :)

Comment: @gung a real value range from 0.0 ~ 10.0

Comment: @DeltaIV Thanks for the advice. Just modified the architecture.

Comment: Ok, so your training data set is $D=\{(\mathbf{s}_i, y_i)\}_{i=1}^N$, where $\mathbf{s}_i$ are strings of bits, and $y_i$ are real numbers between 0 and 1? Or are the $y_i$ binary labels, such as "yes", "no", and you're predicting the probability of $y$ belonging to one class or the other?

Comment: Concerning the vertical strings: it looks like there are two values of $y$ (one is , and the other one seems to be approximately 4.2) which occur multiple times in the training data set, for different values of $\mathbf{s}$. However, according to your plot, $y$ takes values between 0 and 7 (approximately), not 0 and 1...something's wrong. Finally, are you showing a fitted vs expected values for **all the CV-folds together**, or is this the plot for a single fold? Can you show the same plot on the training set, without using Cross Validation?